# Miniature Scale in Blender

Tags: rendering, blender

Has anyone ever tried making models in Blender on a miniature scale? Think original Star Wars effects, like the AT-ATs. Would this make any significant difference in the final render? I imagine that things like trees scaled to three feet might render a little faster than ones true to size.

Answer (score 0):

Just model the objects normally in blender. You alter the distance of the object from the camera or the objects scale to alter the visual size of the object at render time.

By reducing the scale when modelling you only move all the vertices closer together, making modelling harder than it needs to be.

The distance between each vertex will not make any difference to render times, with cycles the number of vertices makes little difference to render times, the size of the texture images makes a bigger performance difference and large images can prevent gpu usage for rendering. Final render times are effected by the resolution of the image and the complexity of textures, glossy reflections and caustics take much longer to render than diffuse textures.